# JavaScript Ajax request for login PHP page not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var a = document.getElementById("log-in");
  a.onclick = function loadXMLDoc() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
          // Something went wrong
          alert("Your browser broke!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("content");
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/login.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send();

    var a = document.getElementById("log-in");
    a.innerHTML = "Sign up";


    a.onclick = function backToIndex() {
      window.location.href = "index.php";
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>CloudBox</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/g3.ico" />
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <header class="shadow-box">
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-img" class="github-img">
      <img src="img/GitHub-Mark-32px.png" alt="github-logo" class="github-logo">
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-link" class="github-link">GitHub link</a>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo-img" class="logo-img">
      <img src="img/g3.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </a>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo-txt" class="logo-txt"><img src="img/logo-text.png" alt="logo-text" class=logo-text"></a>
    <a href="#" id="log-in" class="button-link">Log in</a>
  </header>

  <div id="content" class="content">

    <h1 id="message" class="contentHeader">Cloud platform<br> built from scratch</h1>
    <br>
    <form id="form" method="post">
      <h1 id="contentSignup" class="contentSignup">Sign up</h1>

      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
      <br>

      <input type="text" name="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4,30}" title="4 to 30 alphanumeric characters" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{6,25}" title="6 to 25 alphanumeric characters" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="Submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      <?php include 'register.php';?>
    </form>
  </div>

  <footer id="foot" class="bottom-page">

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<h1 id="message" class="contentHeader">Welcome<br>Please log in</h1>
    <br>
    <form id="form" method="post" style="height:250px;" ">
      <h1 id="contentSignup" class="contentSignup">Log in</h1>
      <input type="text" name="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4,30}" title="4 to 30 alphanumeric characters" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{6,25}" title="6 to 25 alphanumeric characters" placeholder="Password"  required="required" />
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="Submit" name="submits">Submit</button>
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['submits']))
        {

                $user = trim($_POST['username']);
                $pass = trim($_POST['password']);

                $file = "/private/data.csv";
                $handle = fopen($file, "r") or die('ERROR OPEN FILE!');

          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            if ($data[0] == $username && $data[1] == hash('sha256', $password) ){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                header("Location: ./home.php");
                $success = true;
                break;
            }
          }


                if (!$success)
                {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("message").style.color="red";</script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Wrong username or password";</script>';
                }

                fclose($handle);
        }
      ?>
    </form>
```

I have a button which is first set as Log in and the index page is for sign up, then after clicking it the content div of the page will load a login.php page using Ajax request and Sign up value on the button.
The problem is when the ajax request page is loaded I cannot submit, the submit button redirects me to index.php even though it shouldn't.

Comment: You should put the question at the top. It's hard to read little bits of text at the bottom or scattered between long sections of code. People want to understand the issue before having 100's of lines of code thrown in their face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login form needs an `action` attribute, otherwise it defaults to the URL of the current page.

```
<form id="form" method="post" style="height:250px;" action="login.php">
```

Loading it by AJAX doesn't make it default to the AJAX URL.